# webpack: Conflicto entre fuentes e imagenes svg

Tags: nodejs, webpack

Recientemente me surgió un problema al compilar archivos sass con webpack, todo lo hace bien.
El único detalle es que las imágenes svg las agrega a la carpeta de las fuentes y ni siquiera me crea la carpeta `imgs`.

**¿Como puede evitar que pase eso?**

Estoy usando `url-loader` para las imágenes y `file-loader` para las fuentes.

Entrada

```
/proyecto
  |_ scss
     - main.scss
     - logo.svg
     |_ fonts
       - myfont.svg
```

Salida

```
/proyecto
  - css
   - main.css
   |_ fonts
     - [contenthash]-myfont.svg
     - [contenthash]-logo.svg
```

Este es mi código de las reglas:

```javascript
{
  module: {
    rules: [{
      exclude: [/fonts/],
      test: /\.(webp|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [{
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[contenthash]-[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'imgs/',
          limit: 12288
        }
      }]
    }, {
      test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[contenthash]-[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'fonts/'
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```